# Create bone model with screw cavity

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How can we create such this bone model having cavities that perfectly fit with its corresponding screws? I've tried boolean function (all of its variations from intersect, difference, slice, with slicer either bone or the screw) but all I got were the hole on the surface.

By the way the bone model that I'm working with is a bone having thickness of 3 mm, not like the image below.

Image source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxUnWx-Pm3U [image]

My current attempt is to have both the portion of the screw 1 inside the box and the cavities on the box itself.
[image][image]
But my attempt failed as the screw thread was all gone.

2nd edited:
My intended goal was to recreate something similar with this model coming from a paper in 2015 (doi: 10.1007/s00264-015-3106-y). [image].

As you can see in the green circle, there were the cavity in the bone, prepared to be inserted by the screws. I would like to create that one, but in my own bone model, which is hollow inside and has some thickness as shown here
[image].

Comment: Can you show _your_ attempt? It would be easier to answer seeing what does your mesh look like

Comment: you say that bool just made holes on surfaces. In that case your bool has wrong settings that doesn't work on your model... if you insert object into another and use bool it can and should make holes with same topology as inserted object, if it doesn't work as supposed, something is wrong with either settings, your topology or face orientation

Comment: As @Luciano says, it would be good if you could show _your_ attempt. Because I don't know what the actual problem is, if I create some cylinder (to simulate the bone), put a _Boolean_ modifier with _Difference_ on it and take a screw model as the other object, I get a cavity fitting to the screw. What you mean your bone is 3 mm thick, you mean it's a very thin bone or it's a hollow bone with a wall thickness of 3 mm? If it's hollow, where should the cavity be in? When you're drilling a screw in a pipe there's also just a hole in the wall and no cavity around the screw.

Comment: I am sorry I am still new to stack exchange. I just edited my post by adding my attempt. In my edited post I made that box to be assumed as the bone.

Comment: wait, did you want it to show your screw inside of the box that has no mass? I am really not sure right now... I can see that you have thread in your box but it surely won't be visible if there was no mass inside of the box, it needs to be enclosed object to make a hole

Comment: Confusing: your attempt shows a correct boolean result. Either you show the screw as in your 1st image or the hole in the 2nd, unless you're attempting some sort of x-ray view? Have you checked the viewport in Wireframe mode?

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused, too... what you write in your question sounds like you want the screw to be seen as well...? As @Luciano said, do you want some x-ray view or do you mean the cavity should be there, but invisible  because the screw is in there, too? Well, the boolean modifier doesn't delete the screw object which you subtract, why don't you simply make it visible again?

Comment: Thank you for your insights and your kind attention, I've added information about the example I want to follow as well as my bone model.

Comment: I added an answer based on your added info, hopefully someone will have a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You state in your question that your bone model has a 3mm thickness (so hollow, like the box where you demonstrate the problem), but in the samples you show all the bones are solid. That's why you're having trouble showing both the bone and the hole.

I made a crude mockup, but that should give you something to start with:

1. Model the bone object (I added a Solidify Modifier just to make my sample hollow)
2. add the boolean modifier with the screw object(s)
   [image]
   [image]
3. hide the screw object(s) (Disable in Render) so only the bone with the holes is visible
   [image]
4. select some of the faces to be the "window" and assign a transparent material (I added a simple Glass BDSF)
   [image]

You can see that the bone object is visible, the walls are visible as a sort of x-ray view and the holes are visible (I didn't model a screw, but the basic principle is the same)

Comment: Just one addition, although it doesn't matter much for the problem: if you put all the screws in a collection you wouldn't need multiple boolean modifiers ;)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann oh good catch, I didn't know that! I was more focused on solving the transparent bone problem

Comment: yeah well, as I said it doesn't matter much in this case anyway. But it is quite useful if you have multiple (maybe even different) cutting objects and you either do not want to join them into a single object or if they are all the same like those screws but maybe high-poly so that you would prefer instances instead of separate objects. Oh and of course you can always add new cutting objects without having to set up new modifiers - just throw them into the collection.